# Angular Material Theme not applying to lazily loaded modules?

Tags: angular

Apologies for the foolish question but stackoverflow has warned me against deleting it, original appears below but I've figured it out (posted a solution):

I installed angular material theme with 'ng add @angular/material' and selected indigo/pink.

I am attempting to use the  attribute in a template that is a lazily loaded module and it doesn't work. In my module that isn't lazily loaded it works just fine.

In angular.json I have:

```
 "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "src/styles.scss"
    ],
```

And I also edited my src/styles.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink";
```

Despite this I still cannot use a simple thing like color="warn" in a lazily loaded module.

What else do I have to do?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? Maybe an stackblitz project? Lazy loading and angular material styles are not related in functionality. I think your problem is about configuration.

Comment: I think I may just be misunderstanding how to use the theme. The 'color' attribute can't be added to tags like <p> but must be used on particular material widgets, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've just had a conceptual misunderstanding of how the theme and/or CSS work.

I was attempting to say `<p color="warn">` but settings the color in this way only works on particular material widgets. Instead, what I can do is:

```
<p class="mat-error">My error</p>
```